# Using str_replace with a HTML special character?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a string that contains fractions within it.

I therefore want to use the str_replace method to change the slash character $frasl; in to "hello" for the sake of simplicity. However the function doesn't seem to do so.

```
e.g.
$toAdd = "3&frasl;4 teaspoon of sugar";
str_replace("&frasl;", "hello", $toAdd);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you must assign `$toAdd` after replace the word:

```
$toAdd = "3&frasl;4 teaspoon of sugar";
$toAdd = str_replace("&frasl;", "hello", $toAdd);

echo $toAdd;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not done the trick, &frasl; is still being displayed instead of hello.

Comment: @Kyanite what is your output?

Comment: "3&frasl;4 teaspoon of sugar", nothing gets replaced